# I want to embed some input feilds in a tab using the <apex:tab> but its throwing a "TAG MUST BE BETWEEN". can someone help please?

Tags: visualforce

```html
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
    <apex:tab label="info">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title ="User Info">
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}" />
     <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Fax}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Industry}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Rating}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Description}"/>
        
        <apex:selectRadio label="Gender">
            <apex:selectOption itemlabel="Male" itemValue="M" />
            <apex:selectOption itemlabel="Female" itemValue="F" />
        </apex:selectRadio>/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SAVE}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
    </apex:tab>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: The markup you've shown us here is not valid : `</apex:selectRadio>/>`

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation on `<apex:tab>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tab.htm)

> A single tab in an `<apex:tabPanel>`. The `<apex:tab>` component must be a child of a `<apex:tabPanel>`.

So your VF page would need to look something like

```html
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:tabPanel>
        <apex:tab>
            <!-- other tags -->
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```